# How to use java.sql.Timestamp as real java.util.Date with JPA

Tags: java, datetime, jpa, persistence

I have a problem about the management of dates with milliseconds. I understand the need to use the TIMESTAMP to store milliseconds:

```
@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATE_COLUMN", nullable = false)
@Override public java.util.Date getDate() { return this.date; }
```

But if I can't compare this date to another instance of java.util.Date, unless I pay attention to the order of equals() call, because `this.date` instance is a java.sql.Timestamp. How to get a java.util.Date from JPA ? Because the date that comes from JPA, even if the method signature is a java.util.Date is actually an instance of java.sql.Timestamp.

```
java.util.Date newDate = new Date(this.date.getTime());
this.date.equals(newDate) == false
newDate.equals(this.date) == true
```

I've try to modify my method in the persistence class:

```
@Override
public Date getDate() {
  return this.date == null ? null : new Date(this.date.getTime());
}
```

It's working, but it's not efficient with lots of data.

There are other options :

- I could modify the design of my persistence class, using `@PostLoad` in order to create a java.util.Date from the persited date after I retrieve it.
- I wonder if I can not get a result using a `ClassTransformer`?

Have you ever been confronted with this problem? What I do not correctly? What is the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: I just had a very nasty version of this problem where this screwed up Spring Security's salt comparison. Apparently using a sql.timestamp date version for salt renders a different result than using a util.Date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`java.sql.Timestamp` overrides the `compareTo(Date)` method, so it should be no problem using `compareTo(..)`

In short - `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are mutually comparable.

Furthermore, you can always compare the `date.getTime()`, rather than the objects themselves.

And even further - you can use a `long` field to store the date. Or even a `DateTime` (from joda-time)

Comment: Date that comes from persistence is used by another framework that cannot be modified (too many works).

Comment: Because I can't modify the comparison process, I need to provide a java.util.Date to the main system. I would like to know how to convert a date effectively ?

Comment: why do you need to? java.util.Date and java.sql.Timestamp are mutually comparable.

Comment: Look at my test, the result of the method depends on the order of call, and I did not touch this order. I need only a real java.util.Date.

Comment: using `compareTo(..)` should work. Apart from that, you can always compare their `getTime()` rather than the objects.

Comment: I understand your point of view, I think now we should not use the method equals() workjing with Date when it comes to comparing the concept of Time.

Answer (score 15):

TBH, I'm not sure of the exact status of this but there might indeed be a problem with the way  Hibernate (which is your JPA provider, right?) handles `TIMESTAMP` columns.

To map a SQL  `TIMESTAMP` to a `java.util.Date`, Hibernate uses the `TimestampType` which will actually assign a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) to your `java.util.Date` attribute. And while this is "legal", the problem is that `Timestamp.equals(Object)` is **not symmetric** (why on earth?!) and this breaks the semantics of `Date.equals(Object)`.

As a consequence, you can't "blindly" use `myDate.equals(someRealJavaUtilDate)` if `myDate` is mapped to a SQL `TIMESTAMP`, which is of course not really acceptable.

But although this has been extensively discussed on the Hibernate forums, e.g. in [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=927602) and [this one](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=925275) (read all pages), it seems that Hibernate users and developers never agreed on the problem (see issues like [HB-681](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HB-681)) and I just don't understand why.

Maybe it's just me, maybe I just missing something simple for others, but the problem looks obvious to me and while I consider this stupid [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) to be the culprit, I still think that Hibernate should shield users from this issue. I don't understand why Gavin didn't agree on this.

My suggestion would be to create a test case demonstrating the issue (should be pretty simple) and to report the problem (again) to see if you get more positive feedback from the current team.

Meanwhile, you could use a custom type to "fix" the problem yourself, using something like this (taken from the forum and pasted as is):

```
public class TimeMillisType extends org.hibernate.type.TimestampType {

    public Date get(ResultSet rs, String name) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(name);
        if (timestamp == null) return null;
        return
            new Date(timestamp.getTime()+timestamp.getNanos()/1000000);
   }

}
```

Comment: It's crazy. I will try to involve Hibernate again, as you have advised me.

Comment: I created a new issue as I run into the same problem in my application: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6873

Comment: I'd like to thank you for specifying that `Timestamp.equals(Object) is not symmetric`. I had tests falling for Date comparisons, and I tried to trick JPA to return a Date instead of an Timestamp, but all I really had to do was change the order of arguments in `assertEquals`, and it worked like a charm. Thanks for saving me lots of time, even after having had debugged into the deep stack of `assertEquals` 

Answer (score 4):

In my experience you don't want the java.sql.Timestamp out into your logic - it creates a lot of strange errors just as you pointed out, and it does not get any better if your application does serialization.

If it works with the override that returns a new java.util.Date then go for that one. Or even better, go for JodaTime. You'll find lots of examples out on the net doing that. I would not worry about performance here as your database is in magnitude more slow than the creation of a new java.util.Date object.

EDIT:
I see that you are using Hibernate. If you use annotations you can do:

```
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
public DateTime getProvisionByTime() {
    return provisionByTime;
}
```

Then you will get nice DateTime objects from Jodatime in your persistent objects. If you want to only have a date, you can use LocalDate like this:

```
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDate")
public LocalDate getCloudExpireDate() {
    return cloudExpireDate;
}
```

IF you use maven, the following dependencies should get this set up for you (you might need to update the hibernate versions)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Precisely, the java.sql.Timestamp is imposed by JPA. I wish I could do without, but the mapping is provided by JPA...

Comment: As you are using hibernate, I guess you could try the solution I provided above.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is critical for DAO tests:

```
Employer employer1 = new Employer();
employer1.setName("namenamenamenamenamename");
employer1.setRegistered(new Date(1111111111)); // <- Date field

entityManager.persist(employer1);
assertNotNull(employer1.getId());

entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();

Employer employer2 = entityManager.find(Employer.class, employer1.getId());
assertNotNull(employer2);
assertEquals(employer1, employer2); // <- works
assertEquals(employer2, employer1); // <- fails !!!
```

So the result is really surprising and writing tests became tricky.

But in the real business logic you will never use entity as a set/map key because it is huge and it is mutable. And you will never compare time values by `equal` comparison. And comparing whole entities should be avoided too.

The usual scenario uses immutable entity ID for map/set key and compares time values with `compareTo()` method or just using `getTime()` values.

But making tests is a pain so I implemented my own type handlers

http://pastebin.com/7TgtEd3x

http://pastebin.com/DMrxzUEV

And I have overridden the dialect I use:

```
package xxx;

import org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType;
import xxx.DateTimestampType;

import java.util.Date;

public class CustomHSQLDialect extends HSQLDialect {

    public CustomHSQLDialect() {
        addTypeOverride(DateTimestampType.INSTANCE);
        addTypeOverride(new AdaptedImmutableType<Date>(DateTimestampType.INSTANCE));
    }
}
```

I haven't decided yet - would I use this approach both for tests and production or for tests only.

Answer (score 1):

JPA should return a java.util.Date for an attribute of type java.util.Date, the @Temporal(TIMESTAMP) annotation should only affect how the date is stored.  You should not get a java.sql.Timestamp back.

What JPA provider are you using?  Have you tried this in EclipseLink, the JPA reference implementation?

Comment: Hibernate is my JPA provider ;)